# Angular Material Table Filter By All Column

Tags: angular, angular-material

I am trying to to filter all column with using angular material table.Also there is a search which filter alls. When I try to use search and column by filtering it is causing a problem with `filterPredicate`.

Here is my implementation:

```
...

    _filter:{};

      ngOnInit() {
    //it needs to column by filter but causing a problem with using global filter
          this.dataSource.filterPredicate = (data: User, filters: string) => {
            debugger;
            const parsedFilters = JSON.parse(filters);
            return Object.keys(parsedFilters)
              .map(column => {
                return data[column].toLocaleString().trim().toLocaleLowerCase().includes(parsedFilters[column].toLocaleString().trim().toLocaleLowerCase())
              })
              .reduce((acc: boolean, curr: boolean) => (acc = curr) && acc, true);
          }
      }

    //global filter
      public doFilter = (value: string) => { 
            this.dataSource.filter = value.trim().toLocaleLowerCase();
      }
      //column by filter
        public applyFilter(filterValue: string, column: string) {
            this._filter = {
                ...this._filter,
                [column]: filterValue
              };

            if (!filterValue) delete this._filter[column];

        this.dataSource.filter = JSON.stringify(this._filter);

        this.fullSearch = false;

          }
       ...
```

How can I solve this.
Thanks

Comment: Can you create stackblitz of your code?

Comment: @Tushar I think it is clear to understand.

Comment: @tcetin I hope you were able to find the solution to this issue.